# Quanta Plus Themes

Tags: editor, themes, color-scheme

Quanta Plus has a feature to create our own editor themes. However, this requires us to create every little element one at a time.

Isn't there a theme with a dark background (like in GEDit) for Quanta?

If I were to do it one at a time, this can be very tiring. At least a shortcut to it would be nice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I absolutely agree with you.  I can't stand black on white - too much eyestrain.

Try this:

http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/zenburn+-+eye-gentle+Kate+color+scheme?content=66209

It works for Quanta, as well as a bunch of other KDE editors like Kate and Kdevelop.  Just run the install script and it sets up a new KDE schema called zenburn.   Much easier on the eyes.

Comment: Thanks! This is the only schema I found so far that made sense :)